# Pre-populate update form with data from the database

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

UPDATE:

If, in the view, I do `<?php echo $customer->first_name; ?>` it outputs the first-name correctly.

On the same view file `'value' => set_value($customer->first_name)` outputs nothing.

---

I am making a "Customers" CRUD application in CodeIgniter 3. I have an *update form* that I want to pre-populate with the data corresponding to the customer, already existent in he database.

The model looks like this:

```
class Customer extends CI_Model {
  /*Lots
    of
   code*/

 public function getAllCustomers($customer_id) {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('customers', array('id' => $customer_id));
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->row();
    }       
  }
}
```

The controller looks like this:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

/*Lots
    of
   code*/

 public function edit($customer_id){
    $this->load->model('Customer');
    $customer = $this->Customer->getAllCustomers($customer_id);
    $this->load->view('update', ['customer'=>$customer]);
 }
}
```

In the view file (update.php) I have:

```
<?php echo form_input('first_name', '', [
            'type'  => 'text',
            'id'    => 'first_name', 
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'value' => set_value($customer->first_name),
            'placeholder' => 'First name',
    ]); 
?>
```

The customer's first_name, although existent in the the database column called "first_name" does not pre-populate the form.

Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how to do it:

```
<?php echo form_input('first_name', set_value('first_name', $customer->first_name),[
    'id' => 'first_name',
    'class' => 'form-control'
    ]);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

always debug using`$this->db->last_query()` to check your query executing correctly
if `last_query()` doesnot return nothing make sure your set `'save_queries' => TRUE` in `app/config/database.php`

your query might return more than one result

change your model like this

```
 public function getAllCustomers($customer_id) {
    $q = $this->db->get_where('customers', array('id' => $customer_id));
          log_message("error",$this->db->last_query()); //use this to get the complied query for debugging purpose 
        if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
                foreach (($q->result()) as $row) {
                    $data[] = $row;
                }
                return $data;
            }
            return FALSE; 
}
```

if you are sure that your query might return only one result then check `$customer_id` has data in it

```
 public function getAllCustomers($customer_id) {
    if($customer_id){
    $q = $this->db->get_where('customers', array('id' => $customer_id),1); //specify the limit if you want to get only one row
          log_message("error",$this->db->last_query()); //use this to get the complied query for debugging purpose 
        if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {

                return $q->row();
            }

         }
             return FALSE; 

}
```

Comment: `Message: Trying to get property of non-object on line 19` Line 19 is `'value' => set_value($customer->first_name),`

Comment: may be its not the `stdobject` its a array try accessing the firstname like this `$customer['first_name']`

Comment: did `$this->db->last_query()` returns anything?